Syncfusion Flutter Cartesian Charts - how to make Crosshair to follow the chart
I have implemented this chart. I would like to have the Crosshair line to track only along the stepline, so for example in the screen that is here, the current Crosshair shouldn't be allowed. The correct behavior should be that the the Crosshair stays fixed to 70 on the y axis meanwhile I am moving my finger between the start of the chart and the first increment.
Is this possible?


We would like to inform you that CrosshairBehavior is used to view the value of the axis in the tooltip based on the interact position on the chart. However, to show a data point based value we suggest using the TrackballBehavior in the SfCartesianChart. This allows you to display a tooltip for the data points where you touch on the Plot Area. We have shared the user guide documentation link and online sample link for your reference below. Please let us know if you have any further needs.
UG Link,
https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/trackball-crosshair#trackball
Sample Link,
https://flutter.syncfusion.com/#/cartesian-charts/user-interactions/trackball/chart-with-trackball
